# Do I need to configure my laptop dock?

Tags: 10.10, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X61 tablet multitouch computer with a docking station to use DVD player. Can Ubuntu 10.10 or other versions recognize my docking station and DVD player without any special configuration? --This is very important when I install the OS through DVD or CDs.

Thanks,

Xiaodong

Answer (score 1):

I have an X61 (not tablet) w/10.04 that I use with Thinkpad docking station. It required no additional configuration. I use the DVD all the time. I'm reasonably sure your setup will be the same.

Comment: Thinks. I want to use the multitouch function. Wish ubuntu works it too...